# How to Set seed color to Compose + traditional App

Tags: android, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose

I have  a app where it was made kotlin XML based and now 60% of app is in JETPACK compose ,
Now
The theming is like dynamic color applied from application file ,
And for compose
AppTheme file is created where dynamic color is applied,
Now ,
[image]
I want to.give option to select color and now it should take it as seed color and update my apps over all dynamic theme based on seed, how to achieve it ?

So I have app theme file , where theme is created by m3 website.
But this theme is generated by website so is there library or function which provide way to generate this colors and apply in app.